# Why the $L^1(R)$ space does not have a unconditional basis

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

Why the $L^1(R)$  space does not have a unconditional basis. It is a known fact that $L^p(R)$ ($1<p<+\infty$) has unconditional basis. A simple example is the dyadic wavelet or Haar system. I would greatly appreciate it if you can give me some hints of the proof or some related references.

Comment: It is a result due to A. Pełczyński. See https://eudml.org/doc/210865

Comment: You can find a proof in Johnson, Lindenstrauss, *Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces, Volume 1*, p. 10.